# select each letter in order from text

Tags: python

again I would like to help, specifically how I could do it

in order for the script to work like this, I have this script (the function of the script is to select letters from words in order (for example, every second)

for the script below if I `print(GetNthLetters("TSASS",2))`

so the result is `TAS`

but I'm looking for the script so that the result is TAS and then continue and add the rest of the letters according to the same principle

so TAS and would continue from the beginning `TAS + would add SS` so the result would be `TASSS`

could someone help me with this? Thank you

here is mi script

```
def GetEveryLetters(text, n):
    builtstring = ""
    for index, letter in enumerate(text):
        if index % n == 0:
            builtstring = builtstring + letter
    return builtstring
print(GetEveryLetters("TSASS",2))
```

here are a few examples of how I want it to outputs

```
print(GetEveryLetters("TSASS",2))
    TASSS

print(GetNthLetters("TESTTHISIS",3))

TTISEHSITS
```

I would mainly need support there to select more letters than the number of letters, and I don't know how to do that anymore

```
ABS every 2 == ASB
```

thank you very much for your help, I tried to play with it for a long time but it didn't work I came here new to python :D

Comment: still current thanx –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicing makes this trivial:

```
def get_nth_letters(s, n):
  return s[::n]
```

Since this doesn't solve all of your problem, you need to repeat this process, `n` times and join those strings. If `n` is greater than or equal to `len(s)`, this will return a different string than `s`. Otherwise it will just return the same value as `s`.

```
def get_nth_letters(s, n):
  return ''.join(s[i::n] for i in range(n))
```

If we run `get_nth_letters('helloworld', 3)`, the first slice generates `'hlwl'`, the second slice generates `eor`, and the third slice generates `lod`. These are then joined to form `hlwleorlod`.

Comment: Addressed with edit.

Comment: I actually tried it on more than one example and it doesn't work properly sory for problems

Comment: I'm a little uncertain how you get every 5th letter of a 3 letter string.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew but I thought it would work with larger shifts as well
for three letters, for example, every 10

Comment: As @Chris has said, putting the shifts larger than the number of letters will give you a different result, but I believe that's not what your real purpose is, right? Or you want to prevent the user to put the shift larger than your number of letters?

Comment: it will probably be enough like this :D thank you very much :D I will create a separate script for larger shifts @KevinChoonLiangYew

Comment: `def repeat_sequence(sequence, desired_length):
  for i in range(desired_length):
    yield sequence[i % len(sequence)]
print(list(repeat_sequence("123456", 13)))
print(list(repeat_sequence("123456", 13))[12])`